# What is the regular expression to be used for the sequence of strings occured?

Tags: javascript

I have a structure of string, I need a regular expression that only picks up the numbers from the structure, and also the expression should report if the structure deviates from the mentioned rule (suppose if I missed any comma or full stop or braces etc)

The structure is - `{'telugu':['69492','69493','69494'],'kannada':['72224']}`

The regular expression I've tried is  `/\[(.*?)\]/g;`

The above expression is working fine for picking only numbers from the given input, but it's not reporting for the missing of any comma, fullstop or braces etc.

```
var contentids = {'telugu':['69492','69493','69494'],'kannada':['72224']};
var pattern = /\[(.*?)\]/g;

while ((match = pattern.exec(contentids)) != null) {
    var arrayContentids2 = new Array();
    arrayContentids2 = match[1].split(",");
}
```

I am fetching only the numbers from the given input,but I need a validation of missing commas, fullstop, braces etc from the input.

Comment: `contentids` is an object, and objects shouldn't be passed (coerced to string) to check a pattern against... what is your expected output? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Why are you using regular expression for this?? You can simply do `arrayContentids2 = contentids.telugu`

Comment: As mentioned in the question,there is a chance of missing any comma or fullstop or braces in the given input.So,I need to through an warning alert to the user saying the given input does not match the standard input.
Because my server side code fails if I the input is given wrong.

Answer (score 0):

To get all the numbers you can use a RegEx like this `/\'(\d+)\'|\"(\d+)\"/g`. The second part is only for numbers inside `"` instead of `'`, so you can remove this if you want.

To check the balance of braces i would use a simple counting loop and move through the input. I don't think that RegEx are the right tool for this job.

To search missing commas you could use the RegEx `/([\'\"]\s*[\'\"])/g` and `/([\[\(\{]\d+)/g` to find the tow errors in

```
{'telugu':['69492','69493','69494'],'kannada':[72224''72224']}
```

Hope this will help you